# Have CommonJS exports changed in Titanium 8?

Tags: ios, titanium

Ever since updating my Titanium iOS application to use Titanium SDK 8.* (was previously working in 7.5.2.GA), I have been getting errors which seem linked to CommonJS exports.

---

exports.requestMicrophonePermissions = function(callback) {
    //My code
};

---

And I get this message in app:

*undefined is not a function (near '...require('util').requestMicrophonePermissions...')
    at startPermissionRequest@/alloy/controllers/something/something.js:168:49)
    at startController@/alloy/controllers/something_else.js:783:43)
    at startTask@/alloy/controllers/something_else.js:738:22)
    at /alloy/controllers/something_else.js:547:24)*

This seems to be the case for any `exports` function.

Has something changed since 7.5.2.GA?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using your own custom "util" module in your app.   Titanium Mobile now supports a lot of Node.js APIs including util and others.  If you want to you your own util and override the Node.js global module (not recommended), I would change it to be require('/util');  -- which is the correct way of requiring modules.   When you don't use a path in a require statement, it assumes you are trying to load a module from node_modules and checks the standard node_modules paths as defined by Node.js.